# Conditionally create temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I'm using Netezza and need to create a temp table `table1` conditionally based on the value of a variable, say, `$var`

Usually I create a temp table in Netezza as follows.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS
(
 -- statement to fill the data
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

Let's say I have a table t1 like below with some data

```
+---------+
| val     |
+---------+
|       0 |     
|       4 |    
|       8 |    
|      12 |  
|      16 | 
|      20 |
+---------+
```

Based on the value of `$var` I want to select `val` from table and include in the temp table `table1`.

Below is my starting point in code. I need some help with the statement to apply the condition.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS
(
 SELECT * FROM
    (
 -- when `$var` == `all`
  SELECT * FROM t1
-- when `$var` == `above_mean`
  SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE val > mean(val)
   )
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

PostgreSQL compatible Netezza solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type of variable `var` is, or how it would be represented in your create table statement, but you should be able to just take a union of the two queries:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE var = 'all'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE var = 'above_mean' AND val > mean(val)
) DISTRIBUTE ON RANDOM;
```

Comment: `$var` a string type variable